# How do i setup htaccess to allow changes to occur?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-403

below is the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^search/$ search/searchPage.php [L,NC]
```

the .htacess file is located at the root of the website

problem is that it does not exactly take me to searchPage.php when I just type domain.com/search/, it just takes me to a 403 error page (note there is no index.php page here).

This is uploaded in amazon elastic beanstalk

Comment: your use of the ^ caret at the start means starts with search.

Comment: thanks for your comment. could you kindly elaborate? the htaccess is located at the root of the website, and I would want that it default domain.com/search/searchPage.php

Comment: htaccess can be a real pain, why no index.php file? is the search in a real folder, it may be better to put a htaccess in that folder with the basepath set to /search/

Comment: You want to redirect the whole domain to the folder search or only domain.com/search/ = domain.com/search/searchPage.php ?

Comment: yes i move the search page to a new folder created called search. initially it was located in the root, what i want to achieve is that when i type domain.com/searchPage.php?crs_category=Business it does domain.com/search/category/business/ or i can just type that and it refer to unclean url

Comment: Well I think you need to add the first "/" to it. as in RewriteRule ^/search/$ search/searchPage.php [L,NC] or you could just use it without the ^ but then you have to account for the url paramters - here is a good page with some common examples https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489

Comment: with the htaccess still being at the root right? lets say I was to simplify this I have move the search page back to the root. so when  i type domain.com/searchPage.php?crs_category=Business it should rewrite to domain.com/search/category/business/ and where I can just type domain.com/search/category/business/ and it will get that I am referring to  domain.com/searchPage.php?crs_category=Business

Comment: are you using a mvc frame work, because moving the $_GET values to the url body will change how you access them.

Comment: thanks for asking. I am not using any mvc framework I just use regular $_GET

Comment: ok, I asked because rewriting the url in this way moves them from the query the $_GET to the request uri, which can be seen with print_r($_SERVER).  Generally it would be better to use some form of routing class to do such things.

Comment: thanks. I am quite a newbie on this. would you recommend any guide on rooting class? so essentially I wouldn't use htaccess at all

Comment: you would still need a htaccess to hide the index.php page, but you would access the uri ( not url ) part separately, the uri is a virtual path, which is different then the query parameters.  so  take  domain.com/index.php/search?var=1 this is  {url}/{uri}{query} where the url is domain.com/index.php, the uri is 'search' and the query is var=1, so to put the query into the uri changes the nature of it.

Comment: essentially, to do it by hand  you would need to write them like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are basically thinking of it backwards, what you need to do is call the full url and rewrite it to the real one.

like this,

```
  RewriteRule ^search/category/(.+)/ domain.com/search/searchPage.php?crs_category=$1 [L]
```

and then you would use this as your url  http://domain.com/search/category/business/ and rewrite ( not redirect ) it to where it is mapped.  The url in the browser would stay the same.

I am not sure 100% of the .htaccess off the top of my head but that is the method you would use.

Make sense?

The (.+) bit is a capture group and would capture the category and the $1 is where that is output as it is the first capture group.  Some further reading that would help is how to use regular expressions.

As I mentioned a router in the comments, the issue with this method is you have to map each one by hand, which is ok for one or two but can get real ugly real fast.

Comment: make sense. just one small question/ why would I need to write the full url? for I am often working in localhost for testing

Comment: you probably don't need to use the full url.  I just think you need a leading / on it to be the root of the domain.

Comment: so I guess this method is not really recommended. is using htaccess an absolute necessity to clean up url?

Comment: yes htaccess is about the only way to do this, there is no real issue with using it this way.  It's just if you have a lot of them it can get unwieldy, and the real draw back is none of your urls will work without the htaccess, so you could set them up and then latter you put the site on a windows server and have to redo all your urls.  But that might not matter its a case by case kind of thing.